# Overvoltage protection circuit - Serial zener diodes and op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, over-voltage-protection

I need to prevent people from plugging in batteries with incorrect voltage. The 2 cell LiPo with voltage range from 6.4 to 9.8 V is alright, EN=1. But 3 cell LiPo is too much and I need the below circuit to generate EN=0.

The circuit below works as follows:

The positive op-amp input is tied to 3 V reference (Zener D3). The negative input is tied to "voltage-divider" made out of two 5V Zener diodes. The OP then generates EN = 1, if D1, D2 is not conducting (V<sub>bat</sub> < 10 V), or EN = 0 if the D1, D2 are conducting (V<sub>bat</sub> > 10V).

**Question:**

Is this the proper way to generate EN = 0 if 3 cell LiPo is plugged in? I somewhat doubt this, because the op-amp negative input is somewhat floating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTKzWj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Consider what happens with the zeners when the battery voltage is 10.1V

Comment: I replaced the confusing "OP" in your title and post. I presume it means "op-amp" or "OA" as shown on your schematic. What will happen the op-amp itself when the battery polarity is reversed?

Comment: Why is your circuit from right to left?